# fortran code optimization-How to auto-generate the number of times each subroutine has been called

Tags: optimization, fortran, call, subroutine

Is there any way we can figure out how many times each subroutine has been called? not obviously by adding a counter for each subroutine but like a self-generated report after the program finished running by adding some parameters during the ifort or gfortran compile stage ?
I am on a way to optimize my huge code, I think the easiest way is to simplify the subroutine that has been heavily called. Thanks

Comment: Some FORTRAN compilers provide instrumentation if you compile with appropriate compiler flags. Check the documentation for your compiler. Example: http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/stdxe/2013/composerxe/compiler/fortran-lin/GUID-96F454BF-364A-40C9-9B55-BFFAA8FD171D.htm

Comment: This is the sort of job for which many use `gprof` (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gprof) and similar tools.  Intel, for example, produce a range of performance tools, their VTune Amplifier might be of interest.

Comment: Two terms you may look for in the documentation of your compiler are profiling and coverage analysis.